# Copy and show what is after last slash from a cell

Tags: excel

I have columns with words and / between them.
Like this: I/Want/This
Now i want to make a formula that finds the last / and copies or shows only what is behind the last /. In this case i want "I/Want/This" to only show "This" in a cell.

I know this is possible but could not make it work.
Can you guys help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use following formula:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

See image for reference

[image]